# How to calculate contribution of multiple factors to a single dependent variable

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, percentage

I have 4 experiments:

1. control
2. control+factor1
3. control+factor2
4. control+factor1+factor2

Here is the example data of the difference between the sensitivity experiments and control experiment (A=exp[4]-exp[1]; B=exp[2]-exp[1]; C=exp[3]-exp[1]):

```
A: -16.6, -16.8, -17.5, -14.4, -9.8, -7.4, -5.8, -12.3, -9.2, -9.9, -8.5, -1.8, -5.3
B: -12.1, -11.7, -10.9, -10.9, -10.8, -11.2, -11.6, -13, -12.5, -12.2, -10.5,-11.1,-11.9
C: -2.8, -5.0, -6.0, -2.7, 1.5, 5.3, 6.0, 2.5, 3.7, 2.9, 2.4, 10.6, 8.1

avg(A) = -10.4, avg(B) = -11.6, avg(C) = 2.0
corr(A,B) = 0.09, corr(A,C) = 0.97
```

Is there any way to quantify the contribution (as percentage) of factor 1 and 2 to the combined effects (factor1+factor2)? For instance, in terms of the average, B is very close to A, seems factor 1 is the dominant one in the combined experiment.

Comment: What do you mean by, say, `exp[1]`? Are you exponentiating your data ($e^x$)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, exp[1] just means experiment 1.

Comment: hey, did you ever get an answer to your question?